# Create Azure Bot Framework service in Federated subscription

Tags: azure, botframework

We are trying to configure Azure Bot Framework service in federated subscription. initially we used https://dev.botframework.com/ to create out dev service. recently whole functionality has been moved to Azure portal where it can automatically create a app in AD for us.

As our subscription is federated so when we create a service it automatically create AD app into organisation Azure AD instance. I suppose this creating issue for us as it expect app to be created into Microsoft's botframework.com AD tenant(please correct me if my understanding is wrong here). when we use Bot Framework service after that we are getting un-authorized error.

is there any way to force this app to be created in correct place?

Thanks
Harmeet

Comment: "when we use Bot Framework service after that we are getting un-authorized error." are you setting your appId and appPassword correctly in your web.config after the registration?

Comment: Hi @NicolasR , Yes that's correct, we event tried calling token endpoint using curl command and giving unauthorized error.

Comment: Honestly that will be difficult to help you with this problem (at least on my side). Do you see your bot in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList ?

Comment: Could you please add the code you are trying to use?